# VBA/Excel - Sort by date range

Tags: vba, sorting, date, excel

I'm trying to sort an Excel worksheet by date range using VBA. I need to filter for all entries that are within a week of the current date.

The worksheet is arranged into columns (A to S). Column 'I' stores the dates I want filtered.

Below is the latest code i've tried (i've tried a few variations... and just cant figure it out).

```
Dim A As Date
Dim b As String
Dim c As Long
A = Date
A = DateSerial(Year(A), Month(A), Day(A))
b = Format(A - 7, "yyyy, mm, dd")
c = b    
With ActiveSheet
    .Range("$A:$S").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria:=">" & c
    End With
```

Thanks in advance for your help with this.

GTD

Comment: Is this format "yyyy, mm, dd" the format values in column I are formatted? that is very surprising way of storing a Date

Comment: Hi -- date format in column 'I' is mm/dd/yyy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$S$" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=">" & Format(Date - 7, "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim A As Date
A = Date

With ActiveSheet
    .Range("$A:$S").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">" & A - 7
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this for me. It didn't work as i needed it to i'm afraid. It did filter though :). For me, 'Field:=3' should have been 'Field:=9'. Also, it seemed to remove all dates from the filter.